# How to trigger a task in airflow if immediate parent task fails?

Tags: airflow

What i am mainly aiming for is that the restore_denormalized_es_Data should only get triggered when the load_denormalized_es_data task fails. If the load_denormalized_es_data task is successful then the command should be directed to end . Here as you can see , my restore is working when archive fails and load is skipped or retrying as a result i am getting wrong answers.

Have stated the code i am using

```
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
#import files what u want to import

# Airflow level imports
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator,BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

#Imported all the functions and the code is able to call the functions with ease

# Name of the Dag
DAG_NAME = "DAG"

#Default arguments
default_args = {
    "owner": "Mehul",
    "start_date": datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    "provide_context": True
}


# Define the dag object
dag = DAG(
    DAG_NAME,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)
archive_denormalized_es_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "archive_denormalized_es_data",
    python_callable = archive_current_ES_data,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    provide_context =  False,
    dag=dag
    )
load_denormalized_es_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "load_denormalized_es_data",
    python_callable = es_load,
    provide_context = False,
    trigger_rule = TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag
    )
restore_denormalized_es_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "restore_denormalized_es_data",
    python_callable = restore_current_ES_data,
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_FAILED,
    provide_context=False,
    dag=dag
    )   
END = DummyOperator(
    task_id="END",
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag)


    
denormalized_data_creation>>archive_denormalized_es_data>>load_denormalized_es_data
load_denormalized_es_data<<archive_denormalized_es_data<<denormalized_data_creation

load_denormalized_es_data>>restore_denormalized_es_data
restore_denormalized_es_data<<load_denormalized_es_data

load_denormalized_es_data>>END
END<<load_denormalized_es_data

restore_denormalized_es_data>>END  
END<<restore_denormalized_es_data
```

[Here is the picture of the pipelines referred above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTHbt.png)

Comment: It would be easier if you give a minimal complete ***code*** example of what you have so far, and describe what exactly is not working there. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey , I have edited my question so that it is more understandable and have also attached a snippet of code used as well as pic of the pipeline thats causing me the problem . I hope it will be more useful now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to skip the rest of the pipeline if A fails.

[`ShortCircuitOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.0.0/airflow/operators/python.py#L329) will allow Airflow to short circuit (skip) the rest of the pipeline.

Here is an example that does what you outlined.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, ShortCircuitOperator

from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.utils.state import State


def proceed(**context):
    ti = context['dag_run'].get_task_instance(a.task_id)
    if ti.state == State.FAILED:
        return False
    else:
        return True


dag = DAG(
    dag_id="dag",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5),
    schedule_interval='@once',
)

with dag:
    a = PythonOperator(
        task_id='archive_denormalized_es_data',
        python_callable=lambda x: 1
    )

    gate = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id='gate',
        python_callable=proceed,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )

    b = PythonOperator(
        task_id='load_denormalized_es_data',
        python_callable=lambda: 1
    )

    c = DummyOperator(
        task_id='restore_denormalized_es_data',
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_FAILED
    )

    d = DummyOperator(
        task_id='END',
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS
    )

    a >> gate >> b >> c
    [b, c] >> d
```

If `archive_denormalized_es_data` fails, the rest of the pipeline is skipped, meaning Airflow does not run `restore_denormalized_es_data`

[image: A fails]

If `load_denormalized_es_data` fails, `restore_denormalized_es_data` runs and continues to `END`.

[image: B fails]

If `load_denormalized_es_data` succeeds, `restore_denormalized_es_data` is skipped and continues to `END`.

[image: B succeeds]

You code is essentially missing the logic to skip when `archive_denormalized_es_data` fails, which the `ShortCircuitOperator` takes care of for you.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but that won't solve my problem . What I am really looking for is , if there is any way to trigger a task only if a task prior to it is successful or failed . Like I want to trigger a task on the failure of a specific task. It should not depend on anything else .

Comment: I don't understand. What you replied with is not the same as the scenario you posed. Your original problem already does trigger a task on the failure its parent task with trigger rule. The issue that when A fails, B also fails, which triggers C and that is not what you wanted. The solution here skips the rest of the pipeline, which does not trigger C as expected. Please clarify the problem statement, provide a minimum reproduction of the DAG, or a visual of the desired outcome.

Comment: Hey , I have edited my question so that it is more understandable and have also attached a snippet of code used as well as pic of the pipeline thats causing me the problem . I hope it will be more useful now

Comment: I didn't change anything about the answer except the task ids and added images so it's easier for you visualize. I still think the answer works. Please let me know explicitly what the answer doesn't address if it does not work.

Comment: Hey , The above given code works fine . But now i have another problem . Since we are using shortcircuit operator , all the tasks after after gate are getting skipped . As a result the end result of dag shows successful whereas it should have failed since my archive failed . I cannot use none_skipped_or failed as trigger rule too as we are also using branchpythonoperator to selectively run tasks before archiving data . Is there anyway to not skip the end task ?

Comment: Further more if we are not selecting this branch i.e. this branch is skipped then also this gate is getting triggered and as a result the whole branch is skipped till end. This is the python function i used { def proceed_collibra(**context): ti = context['dag_run'].get_task_instance(archive_collibra_es_data.task_id) if ti.state == State.SUCCESS: return True else: return False

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how the ShortCircuitOperator works. There are a few github issues describing the complete downstream task fails. See https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/7858 for more information.